# Converting particular values to NA in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
> head(newdat2)
   i42 i35 i32 i31 i30 i29 i28 i27 i26
1    5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   
5    3   3   2   2   4   4   4   3   2      
6    5   5   5   2   5   5   5   5   5      
7    5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5      
8    4   5   4   3   5   4   4   3   4      
11   3   2   2   6   2   4   2   2   2
```

I would like to convert any values that are not 1,2,3,4, or 5 to NAs.  How could I go about doing this?  I have tried the following:

```
newdat2[(newdat2!=1)|(newdat2!=2)|(newdat2!=3)|(newdat2!=4)|(newdat2!=5)]<-NA
```

But this just makes all the values NA I also also tried some combos of sapply and ifelse, but nothing is working.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: Use `%in%`  for that

Comment: Ok and how should I use it?

Comment: @user227710 this question is less obvious than it might seem. In fact as the excellent answer of David shows it can't be solved with just a `%in%` but with a little more complicated code.

Comment: @SabDeM: I just gave  a hint not a solution, and hence the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation of the `is.na<-` replacement function

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) `is.na<-`(x, !x %in% 1:5))
#    i42 i35 i32 i31 i30 i29 i28 i27 i26
# 1    5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
# 5    3   3   2   2   4   4   4   3   2
# 6    5   5   5   2   5   5   5   5   5
# 7    5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
# 8    4   5   4   3   5   4   4   3   4
# 11   3   2   2  NA   2   4   2   2   2
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you, but can you explain why the brackets come after the initial df?

Comment: In order to retain the `data.frame` structure, you can test by running it without them and see what you get (hint - a list).

Comment: Or a data.table option is `setDT(df); for(j in seq_len(ncol(df))){
 set(df, i=which(!df[[j]] %in% 1:5), j=j, value=NA)
 }`

Comment: @akrun that's anice one, I was thinking to do a similar thing with just `lapply` and `:=`, but figured the base R is good enough for this task because of the shallow copy.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can be made to work, you just need to get the boolean logic right. David Arenburg's answer offers a cleaner approach anyway, but you may find it useful to understand "what went wrong" with your attempt.

Note that `(x!=1)|(x!=2)` will evaluate to true for both 1 and 2 (as well as any other number): when `x` is 1 the `x!=2` clause is true, and when `x` is 2 the `x!=1` clause is true. To get all numbers that are neither 1 nor 2 you want to use the `&` connective: `(x!=1)&(x!=2)`. This is an application of one of two extremely useful principles known as [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which state that, for any boolean expressions `P` and `Q`, `!(P or Q) == (!P) and (!Q)`, and `!(P and Q) == (!P) or (!Q)`.

It is not too hard to show that this extends to arbitrarily many expressions, so in your case the correct code would be

```
newdat2[(newdat2!=1)&(newdat2!=2)&(newdat2!=3)&(newdat2!=4)&(newdat2!=5)]<-NA
```